# How to separate elapsed time in three parts?

Tags: php, timestamp

In `$periods` array first column is for single day (1 godinu), second is for more then one (2 godine) and third is the same but after 4 days in my country, we say different (5 godina).
And it is different for everything, here is an example for all of them:

```
year = (1 = godinu), (2,3,4 = godine), (after 4 = godina)
month = (1 = mesec), (2,3,4 = meseca), (after 4 = meseci)
week = (1 = nedelju), (2,3,4 = nedelje), (after 4 = nedelja)
day = (1 = dan), (after 1 = dana)
hour = (1 = sat), (2,3,4 = sata), (after 4 = sati)
minute = (1 = minut), (after 1 = minuta)
second = (1 = sekund), (2,3,4 = sekunde), (after 4 = sekundi)
```

```
<?php
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $periods = array(
        'y' => ['godinu', 'godine', 'godina'],
        'm' => ['mesec', 'meseca', 'meseci'],
        'w' => ['nedelju', 'nedelje', 'nedelja'],
        'd' => ['dan', 'dana', 'dana'],
        'h' => ['sat', 'sata', 'sati'],
        'i' => ['minut', 'minuta', 'minuta'],
        's' => ['sekund', 'sekunde', 'sekundi']
    );

    $parts = array();
    foreach ($periods as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $parts[] = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v[$diff->$k > 1];
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $parts = array_slice($parts, 0, 1);
    return $parts ? 'pre ' . implode(', ', $parts) : DATE_NOW;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you add some examples on what you expect. Date now, Input date, Explected output.

Comment: @JasonK In english, there is YEAR and YEARS...in my country there is GODINU (first year), GODINE (from 2 to 4) and GODINA (from 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct units for each value can easily be chosen using a simple [`switch` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```php
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $periods = array(
        'y' => ['godinu', 'godine', 'godina'],
        'm' => ['mesec', 'meseca', 'meseci'],
        'w' => ['nedelju', 'nedelje', 'nedelja'],
        'd' => ['dan', 'dana', 'dana'],
        'h' => ['sat', 'sata', 'sati'],
        'i' => ['minut', 'minuta', 'minuta'],
        's' => ['sekund', 'sekunde', 'sekundi']
    );

    $parts = array();
    foreach ($periods as $k => $v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            switch ($diff->$k) {
                case 1:
                    $unit = $v[0];
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    $unit = $v[1];
                    break;
                default:
                    $unit = $v[2];
            }
            $parts[] = $diff->$k . ' ' . $unit;
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $parts = array_slice($parts, 0, 1);
    return $parts ? 'pre ' . implode(', ', $parts) : DATE_NOW;
}

echo time_elapsed_string('last month -8days -3hours', true);
// pre 1 mesec, 1 nedelju, 1 dan, 2 sata, 59 minuta, 59 sekundi
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question. Its wokring perfectly!